# Xamarin Studio code completion and navigation not working

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, autocomplete

Yesterday I upgraded Xamarin Studio on my Mac `(10.12.4)` to `6.1.5 (build 0)` community edition.

If I create a new project, everything works as expected, but in my existing solution that is quite extensive, code completion, symbol navigation *(e.g., right-clicking a symbol to find references)*, and brace matching are all not functioning.

**Note:** It seems to be functioning properly in XAML files, but not CS files. This is strange, since everything I could find searching appears to suggest the opposite is the most likely circumstance.

**Here are the things I've tried so far to remedy it:**

- Removing and reinstalling Xamarin Studio
- Deleting all Xamarin-related files from `~/Library/` and `~/Library/Caches`
- Turning off the related settings, then back on
- Restarting my Mac

It may be worth noting that in the area above the text editor, I see the following 'no selection' message, no matter what I do in the file:

[image: Xamarin autocomplete broken]

and if I select a symbol, the menu is always greyed out:

[image]

I have not seen anything that appears to be relevant in the IDE logs, and I have tried everything I can think of at this point.

Does anyone out there have any suggestions on what to try next, or how to debug this issue?

Lastly, on another Mac with the same version of Xamarin Studio, I am unable to reproduce, and we're both pulling from the same git repo.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your solution ` [solution].ncb or [solution].suo` (when closed)? After you would open the solution and rebuild.

Comment: I don't see any .suo or .ncb files in the directory tree...

Comment: In your solution folder.

Comment: Xamarin Studio does not use a .suo file. Instead try deleting the <solutionname>.userprefs file from the root solution directory. Close Xamarin Studio first and after deleting the .userprefs file try re-opening the solution and testing.

Comment: Works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@jgoldberger was correct. Deleting `<solution_name>.userprefs` and re-opening Xamarin Studio has restored the functionality of the code completion and related features.

Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone is running into this issue in Visual Studio Mac with XForms (I'm using VS Mac 7.4.3 and XForms 2.3.4)...there's a hidden directory in the solution root directory called '.vs'. You'll want to delete that and then restart Visual Studio. Viola, alll better! :D

Comment: @JonScalet That worked for me on Mac! Thank you very much. That was a very annoying issue.