# "Visual Studio for Mac" Code Completion Barely Working In Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I'm using "Visual Studio for Mac" and the code completion for Xamarin.Android is terrible. Here's a screenshot of me trying to add some menu code to my MainActivity.cs. When I finish typing everything, the compiler does not complain but the lack of suggestions is troubing.

Is there a way to "turn on" code completion?

[image]

Comment: Definitely not my experience, what version of VS4M are you using?

Comment: I'm using "Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac" Version 7.2 (build 636)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Terrible. I've Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 for Mac and nothing changes if compared to Community Edition. That happens in both file types (xaml, cs, ....)
Hope some fix as soon as it can...

Comment: Product defects like this should be reported to Microsoft via Help | Report a Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem using Xamarin Forms on 19 Nov 2017 in 7.2.2.

The fix for me was deleting `<solution_name>.userprefs` and re-opening Xamarin Studio
 as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303880/xamarin-studio-code-completion-and-navigation-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the answer for me was that autocompletion was already on, I just wasn't triggering it correctly. In my experience, typing the function name immediately following the `override` keyword would correctly display the autocompletion suggestions, whereas placing the return type after the override keyword, even though syntactically correct, would throw off the autocompletion.